# Intel 5100 AGN card doesn't work on Trisquel 8

Tags: debian, ubuntu, wifi, iwlwifi, trisquel

I recently installed Trisquel 8 on a Thinkpad X200T with an Intel 5100 AGN card, and the WiFi did not work after my initial installation. I searched across various other forums for instructions to enable Trisquel to use the card, and I attempted to follow their instructions, but to no avail.

My networking hardware switch is set to on, I have the necessary firmware in the `/lib/firmware` directory, and I did load the `iwlwifi` module using modprobe, but the WiFi still does not work, and `ifconfig` and `rfkill` do not even show a wireless controller (rather, it only shows the ethernet and loopback systems).

Would somebody please help me? Thank you!

EDIT: I am aware that the `firmware-iwlwifi` is non-free, but I can't use a free WiFi device right now. I know that using it contradicts Trisquel's philosophy, but I know that I can still install it.

Answer (score 2):

The Intel 5100 AGN  wifi card require a proprietary software ([`firmware-iwlwifi`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/firmware-iwlwifi) `non-free`).  As defined in the tag info [trisquel](/questions/tagged/trisquel) *reuses Ubuntu packages and avoids using `non-free` packages*.

Installing a non-free software on a [GNU distribution](https://www.gnu.org/distros/free-distros.en.html) doesn't make sense, it conflict with the [philosophy](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/philosophy.html) of the gnu project.

To get the wifi working you need a PCI wifi card or a usb wifi device supported by a free software. Here is a list of suggestions on [debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi).

Comment: I know that it is non-free, but I cannot buy a free WiFi card right now. I updated the question to clarify this.